# What is the difference between API-Misuse and Bug Prone API?

Tags: api

I require a clear picture of the terms **API-Misuse** and **Bug Prone API**. Could you please explain the terms with a simple example. Let's say, when a developer forgets to close a resource, it is API-Misuse, but when an API will be treated as a Bug Prone API. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API Misuse results from a caller to an API that has an issue.

The Bug Prone API is due to an API implementation that has issues with inputs that should be handled correctly.

It's like the driver of a vehicle that makes a mistake and causes an accident (API Misuse), or the car that had brakes that failed even though the driver did everything right (Bug Prone API).